# GROUP_CONCAT and LEFT_JOIN - filter records

Tags: mysql, sql, join, concatenation

The following query displays a list of soups and, for each soup, a list of the ingredients.

```
     //Query only for demonstration

     SELECT a.id_soup, a.soup,      
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.id_vegetables) AS vegetables_id,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.vegetables) AS vegetables_list   
     FROM soups a   
     LEFT JOIN ingredients ing ON a.soup = ing.soup_id
     LEFT JOIN vegetables b ON b.id_vegetables = ing.list_vegetables
     GROUP BY a.id_soup
```

I want to filter the records so that only the ones in which the soup has a certain ingredient (for example, potatoes) are displayed. Something like:

```
     SELECT a.id_soup, a.soup,      
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.id_vegetables) AS vegetables_id,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.vegetables) AS vegetables_list   
     FROM soups a   
     LEFT JOIN ingredients ing ON a.soup = ing.soup_id
     LEFT JOIN vegetables b ON b.id_vegetables = ing.list_vegetables

     AND ing.list_vegetables LIKE "potatoes"

     GROUP BY a.id_soup
```

These query filters the records, but the list of ingredients no longer displays all the ingredients of the soup, just displaying the ingredient potatoes.

What is the best way to do this correctly?

**EDITED:**

With multiple conditions - PHP and SQL:

```
  $typesQuery = "";
  $bind=array();

  sqlQuery = "SELECT a.id_soup, a.soup, a.restaurant,      
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.id_vegetables) AS vegetables_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.vegetables) AS vegetables_list
  FROM soups a   
  LEFT JOIN ingredients ing ON a.soup = ing.soup_id
  LEFT JOIN vegetables b ON b.id_vegetables = ing.list_vegetables ";

 if($restaurant)  {
    $sqlQuery .= " AND a.restaurant LIKE ? ";
    $typesQuery .= "s" ;
    $bind[] = $restaurant;
 }


 if($vegetables)  {
    $sqlQuery .= " AND ... ";
    $typesQuery .= "s" ;
    $bind[] = $vegetables;
 }

 //EDITED:
 $vegetables = 'potatoes';
 if($vegetables)  {
    $sqlQuery .= " HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN b.vegetables IN (?) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 ";
    $typesQuery .= "s" ;
    $bind[] = $vegetables;
 }


 $sqlQuery .= " GROUP BY a.id_soup LIMIT ?,? ";

 if ($statementQuery = $conexion->prepare($sqlQuery)){

    $typesTotal = $typesQuery;
    $bindTotal = array_merge(array(), $bind);

    $typesQuery .= "ii"; 
    $bind[] = $start;
    $bind[] = $limit;
    array_unshift($bind, $typesQuery);
    call_user_func_array(  array($statementQuery, 'bind_param'), makeValuesReferenced($bind) );

 }else{
    $error = $conexion->error;
    $success = false;
    break;
 }
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) after you get the vegetables list.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT a.id_soup, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.id_vegetables) AS vegetables_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.vegetables) AS vegetables_list   
FROM soups a   
LEFT JOIN ingredients ing ON a.soup = ing.soup_id
LEFT JOIN vegetables b ON b.id_vegetables = ing.list_vegetables
GROUP BY a.id_soup
) X
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('POTATOES',VEGETABLES_LIST) > 0
```

Comment: I've been testing your solution in the simple example of my post and it works great. However I could not apply to my real case, because it is filtering with multiple conditions. I edited my post. Thanks in advance if you have any more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just a conditional having clause?

```
SELECT a.id_soup, a.soup,      
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.id_vegetables) AS vegetables_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.vegetables) AS vegetables_list

FROM soups a   
LEFT JOIN ingredients ing ON a.soup = ing.soup_id
LEFT JOIN vegetables b ON b.id_vegetables = ing.list_vegetables
GROUP BY a.id_soup
HAVING sum(case when b.vegetables in ('potatoes') then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

If you wanted to find recipes that had both potatoes and cheese you could add cheese to the in clause and change the value to be =2

`HAVING sum(case when b.vegetables in ('potatoes','cheese') then 1 else 0 end) = 2`

This assumes each ingredient would only be listed once per recipe.

Since you know the ingredients you're looking for you can dynamically adjust the equality count in the having.

Comment: I've been testing your solution in the simple example of my post and it works great too. I edited my post with multiple conditions case. Thanks in advance if you have any more suggestions.

Comment: I don't see the problem if `'potatoes'` and `1` from above become bound parameters the `'potatoes'` could be `'potatoes','chicken','pork'` while the 2nd parameter would be `3` (the count of the 3 items in the array)

Comment: Thanks xQbert. I edite my post. I like your solution, but I still have not been able to make it work in my case. I also tried to put this part of the query after GROUP BY, but it also did not work. I'm doing several tests trying to figure out what's going on.